# Excel VBA to fill blank cells based on values in cell before it

Tags: vba, excel

I am new to VBA Excel.

I am working on an excel macro to fill a certain value in all blank rows in a cell based on the values in another cell.

Say for example, we have on one row :

```
blank1 blank2 blank3 AR blank4 blank5 DP blank6 blank 7 AR blank8 blank9 DP blank10 bl1nk11
```

I want all blanks before AR to be filled with "OV" and all blank cells before "DP" to be filled with "OS"

Please help me with this, I will be able to integrate it into my big code.

Thanks.

Comment: What code do you have? What's the problem with it? StackOverflow is here to help you with problems, it's not here as a free code-writing service. If you don't understand a specific part of VBA, then it's best to focus your question on that. E.g. "how do I replace the text in a string with a different text"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally we like you to post what you have done so far but I was curious if I would be able to code this or not. So! Try this. If you need to do this over a multiple rows you could just add another loop and change the 1 to a variable. Hope this helps!

```
Option Explicit

Sub FillEmpty()

    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim myRange As Range
    Dim lColumn As Long
    Dim x As Integer

    Set ws = Worksheets("Sheet1")

    'Find the last column that contains data
    lColumn = ws.Cells.Find(What:="*", _
        After:=ws.Cells(1, 1), _
        LookAt:=xlPart, _
        LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
        SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, _
        SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, _
        MatchCase:=False).Column

    With ws
        For x = lColumn To 2 Step -1
            If .Cells(1, x) = "AR" Then
                .Cells(1, x - 1).Value = "OV"
            ElseIf .Cells(1, x) = "DP" Then
                .Cells(1, x - 1).Value = "OS"
            ElseIf .Cells(1, x).Value <> "" And .Cells(1, x - 1).Value = "" Then
                .Cells(1, x - 1).Value = .Cells(1, x).Value
            End If
        Next x
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for this. It worked like magic. Apologies for not uploading the work done so far. This is my first time using StackOverflow since i joined.